# Let $(1+x+x^2)^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_{2n}x^{2n}$ be an identity in $x$. Find $a_0 +a_2 +a_4+ \cdots +a_{2n} $ in terms of $n$

Tags: polynomials

> Let $(1+x+x^2)^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots+a_{2n}x^{2n}$ be an identity
>   in $x$. Find $a_0 +a_2 +a_4+ \cdots +a_{2n} $ in terms of $n$.

I honestly don't know how to get started with this one.

I know this problems calls for the Binomal Theorem but the $2n$ index of the last term is making this difficult for me to get in some kind of nice form where it's clear what $a_1 +a_2+\cdots +a_n$ stands for in terms of $n$.

Can you guys give me some hint ?

Comment: Set $x=-1,1$ & add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I give explicitly solution based on the guidance of @lab bhattacharjee.

Substituting $x=1$ into the equality we have
$$
3^n=a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3+\ldots+a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}.
$$
Substituting $x=-1$ into the equality we have
$$
1=a_0-a_1+a_2-a_3+\ldots-a_{2n-1}+a_{2n}.
$$
Adding two above equalities, we get
$$
2(a_0+a_2+\ldots+a_{2n-2}+a_{2n})=3^n+1.
$$
Therefore
$$
a_0+a_2+\ldots+a_{2n-2}+a_{2n}=\frac{3^n+1}{2}.
$$